# Updating a document in Solr using SolrJ

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have following indexed data in Solr. I want to add an extra field "Location" in this indexed data using SolrJ. How can I do this?

```
"response":{"numFound":3061,"start":3059,"docs":[
      {
        "Id":12345,
        "Name":"Rajeev Kumar",
        "_version_":1223434645768768687},
      {
        "Id":67890,
        "Name":"Rohit Kumar",
        "_version_":1246457656544545434}]
  }}
```

After updating it should look like this -

```
"response":{"numFound":3061,"start":3059,"docs":[
      {
        "Id":12345,
        "Name":"Rajeev Kumar",
        "Location" : <some value>,
        "_version_":1223434645768768687},
      {
        "Id":67890,
        "Name":"Rohit Kumar",
        "Location": <some value>,
        "_version_":1246457656544545434}]
  }}
```

I tried something like this -

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException, IOException {

            String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted";
            HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
            solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
            SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
            HashMap<String, Object> value = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
            value.put("set","Delhi"); 
            document.addField("Location", value); 
             solr.commit();
    }
```

But the problem is that this is creating a new document instead of updating the old document. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include the id part in your document values, otherwise Solr isn't able to find the original document to update. This should be a uniqueKey field.

```
document.addField("Id", 12345);
```

You can't perform an update against multiple documents in one request, so each document has to be updated by itself.

Comment: Ok. I have added the unique key but then the error is coming as undefined field "Location". Should I need to add "Location" in schema.xml before updating?

Comment: Yes, the field must exist in the schema unless you're using the schemaless mode.

Comment: Can you please provide a source for your claim that you “can't perform an update against multiple documents in one request”? [The API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrClient.html#add-java.util.Collection-) provides an overloading that accepts a sequence of `SolrInputDocument` objects. Then again, the documentation does not mention document updates at all.

Comment: You can submit multiple, new documents (or multiple atomic update instructions of said documents, but they all have to be identified by an ID), which is what you're linking to. This is not the same as "update by query", which is analogous to `UPDATE foo SET a = 1 WHERE field = 'bar'`. In the API method you've linked, you already have the documents available, instead of asking Solr to update a set of documents identified by a query (`field:bar`).